# If interpreting Conifold is on-topic, should interpreting GPT-4 also be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Not much to add to the title.

This question is on-topic: [How, in layman's terms, should this Conifold argument against illusionism be interpreted?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/99656/66156)

But my recently asked question is getting close votes: [Analyzing GPT-4's mathematical formalization of libertarian free will](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/100318/66156)

If interpreting Conifold is on-topic, should interpreting GPT-4 also be on-topic?

Comment: The whole “interpreting Conifold” thing is creepy and inappropriate. It comes off as cult-like. I guess it’s supposed to be somewhat humorous, but I find it cringey. It also sets the precedent of singling out a single contributor for special treatment. Conifold is no more special in my mind than any other anonymous contributor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If interpreting Conifold is on-topic, should interpreting GPT-4 also be on-topic?

It could be on-topic. The issue is not whether the source being analyzed is a human being or a software program. What matters is the quality and research effort that an OP reflects. The level of [[in-]accuracy of a source](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63900071#63900071) is independent of the effort that is expected from an OP.

When it comes to GPT, though, the OP has by default an uphill battle in that such software is widely known to produce inaccurate output. It is up to the OP to highlight why in his specific instance GPT's output should not be singlehandedly dismissed.

Identifying the *details* of GPT-4's output that are hard for you to grasp is likely to prompt knowledgeable contributors to address the question. Instead, the closed post amounts to asking GPT-4 to do your assignment and then having us validate it. More specifically, the question "*Does GPT-4's formalization make sense given our current understanding of physics?*" is an obvious change of "*am I right?*" (see the stated reason for closing) to "*is the program right?*". It evidently involved no research effort.

In the post about interpreting Conifold's argument, the user asked for some starting point(s) that could help him make sense of that argument. This is different from asking "*is Conifold right?*". Furthermore, the pair of links the user provided suggest that he made at least some effort to acquaint himself with the matter at issue. This showing might be what prompted a few contributors to go the extra mile and post elaborated answers.